# NBA Team Scoring Averages 2015 vs 2014

Tags: nba

What is the NBA's average team score from season to season; 2014 season vs 2015 season?

Answer (score 2):

These charts show each team's average points per game as well as a bunch of other stats:

[NBA Team Statistics Comparison 2014/15](http://espn.go.com/nba/statistics/team/_/stat/team-comparison-per-game/sort/avgPoints/year/2015)

[NBA Team Statistics Comparison 2015/16](http://espn.go.com/nba/statistics/team/_/stat/team-comparison-per-game)